# c++ code organisation with svn and cmake

Tags: svn, code-organization

I am working on several C++ projects on my local computer. They all use some common libs and headers. The file structure is like this:

```
-bin
-lib
-include
-devel
   -project1
      -src
   -project2
      -src
-doc
```

I am using Eclipse IDE and i set all the relative paths. It compiles the executables to the bin folder and uses libs/includes within the structure. It works fine.

Now I need to import all the projects into an SVN repository so that different people can access and develop codes.

And i wondering if there is a way to have this structure in the SVN server? So when someone checks out a project, he can just start working on it without organising the libs or headers. He will just check out, and all the relative linking will be done. Can i use CMake for this purpose?

I am using Eclipse with subclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

SVN can already maintain such a folder hierarchy. If you used some svn interface like Turtoise SVN, you would just need to right click on a node and select "Add Folder" and it will automatically add all the sub folders and files in them into the repository.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am using Eclipse with subclipse plugin. And when i checkout the whole file structure, it threats the main directory as a project in the workspace. So i cant compile the separate project within Eclipse.

Comment: When i import the whole structure to SVN and checkout in the console, i can point the Eclipse workspace to "devel" folder. It works but this time the problem would be, the binaries will be written to "bin" folder when a user compile it in Eclipse and this user should commit the changes in the "bin" from the console again. Committing in eclipse wouldnt be enough since "bin" folder is outside of the workspace.

Comment: @user2148564, you can re-commit whole directory structure instead of only devel folder. svn will detect changed files and update the repository accordingly.

Comment: How can i do it in Eclipse? Since my workspace is the "devel" folder. If i set the workspace to the main folder, i cant compile the codes.

Comment: @user2148564, how do you commit the project into SVN?

Comment: First i manually import it from the console with "svn import" command. Then i checked the whole structure out to a folder. Then i set the Eclipse workspace to the "devel" folder.